# AngularJS easy example doesn't work in Plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I don't understand why this simple example doesn't work in Plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EfNxzzQhAb8xAcFZGKm3?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("App",[]);

var Controller = function($scope){

  $scope.message ="Hello";
};


app.contoller("Controller",['$scope',Controller]);


var app = angular.module("App",[]);

var Controller = function($scope){

  $scope.message ="Hello";
};


app.contoller("Controller",['$scope',Controller]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plunker offers out-of-the-box angular syntax to get you started with best practices:

Check this out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: I don't think the above code should be considered best practice. Check this out https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 3):

You misspelt `controller` as `contoller`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example to get you started with **"Controller as"** syntax, which is what you should use going forward. You'll see lots of examples of the **$scope** syntax, but it is no longer the recommended way to bind controllers to views. See  [AngularJS.org's documentation regarding ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) for more details.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aydvXaJNXtzdVI1mh2I4?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="controllerAsDemo">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <p ng-controller="MainController as main">Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
    <p ng-controller="BillyGoatController as billyGoat">Hello {{billyGoat.name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('controllerAsDemo', []);

app.controller('MainController', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
});

app.controller('BillyGoatController', function() {
  this.name = 'Billy Goat Gruff';
})
```